# I updated vuetify and vue js versions. However, when running the yarn serve command I get this error

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, vuex

This relative module was not found:

- ./assets/images/ajax-loader.gif in ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--8-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/vuetify-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--18-0!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&

Answer (score 0):

You should probably reinstall your `node_modules`:

```sh
rm -rf ./node_modules && yarn install
```

Welcome to JavaScript !

Comment: I tried it before you wrote it. However, this time I ran into another error.    error  in ./node_modules/vuetify/src/components/VTreeview/VTreeview.sass

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):

    @content($material-light)
   ^
      Invalid CSS after "    @content": expected "}", was "($material-light); "
      in C:\Users\omur.ozbek\Desktop\vf-bireysel-frontend - Kopya\node_modules\vuetify\src\styles\tools\_theme.sass (line 3, column 5)